# CSH Group Existance Test With Value Test

Tags: csh

In CSH, is it possible to nest the test for an existance of a variable with the test for its value in the same if-clause?

```
#!/bin/csh

# This seems to work...
if ( $?VAR ) then
    echo "VAR exists"        
    if ( $VAR == true ) then
        echo "VAR is true"
    endif
endif

# I want something more like this:
if (( $?VAR ) && ( $VAR == true )) then
    echo "VAR exists and is true"
endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short-circuit evaluation is one of the [many things that C shell doesn't do](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/). You will have to use nested `if` statements or switch shells.